# How does the optimizer in tensorflow access the variables created in a separate function

Tags: python, tensorflow, namespaces

**Lines of interest in code are followed by multiple hash (#)symbols**

For understanding purpose i am running a simple linear regression in tensorflow. The code im using is:

```
def generate_dataset():
#y = 2x+e where is the normally distributed error
x_batch = np.linspace(-1,1,101)
y_batch = 2*x_batch +np.random.random(*x_batch.shape)*0.3
return x_batch, y_batch

def linear_regression():   ##################
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None,), name = 'x')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape = (None,), name = 'y')
with tf.variable_scope('lreg') as scope: ################
    w = tf.Variable(np.random.normal()) ##################
    y_pred = tf.multiply(w,x)
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_pred - y))
return x,y, y_pred, loss
def run():
x_batch, y_batch = generate_dataset()
x, y, y_pred, loss = linear_regression()
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.2).minimize(loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as session:
    session.run(init) 
    feed_dict = {x: x_batch, y: y_batch}
    for _ in range(30):
        loss_val, _ = session.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict)
        print('loss:', loss_val.mean())
    y_pred_batch = session.run(y_pred, {x:x_batch})

    print(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES)) ############
    print(session.run(fetches = [w])) #############
run()
```

I can't seem to be able to fetch the values of variable (is it actually an op?) 'w' with a fetch call to either 'w' or 'lreg/w', which if i understand correctly is due to the fact that 'w' is defined in linear_regression() and it does not lend its namespace to run(). However, i can access 'w' with a fetch call to its variable name 'lreg/vairable:0'. optimizer works just fine and updates are applied perfectly

How is the optimizer accessing 'w' and applying the updates and it would be great if you can give me a little insight into how the op 'w' is shared between linear_regression() and run()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every op and variable that you create is a node in a tensorflow [graph](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Graph). When you don't explicitly create a graph, like in your case, then there is a default graph that is used.

This line adds w to the default graph.

```
 w = tf.Variable(np.random.normal())
```

This line accesses the graph to perform the computation

```
loss_val, _ = session.run([loss, optimizer], feed_dict)
```

You can inspect the graph like this

```
tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
```

Comment: thank you very much for the response. i have a followup question: Why is  print(session.run(fetches = [w])) when run from run() throwing up an error? NameError: name 'w' is not defined. would like to remind you that print(session.run(fetches = ['lreg/variable:0']) does fetch me the value of 'w'

Comment: You have to keep python variables and tensorflow variables separate in your mind. Just because the Tensorflow graph has a variable called w in it doesn't mean that python has a variable called w defined within the current scope.